# Cannot view item on list webpart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a Page and a List

The page displays a WebPart of the list

But from the WebPart I cannot click to view the full item of the list

Are there any workarounds?

Comment: do you want to go to the list view page when you click on WebPart link?

Answer (score 1):

If you have kept the WebPart on the page to show the List data then by default the list title is displayed which is clickable link and it always redirect us to the complete list view.

If that title is missing in your case as I guessed then you can follow this steps:

- Edit the page
- Edit the WebPart
- Find `Appearance` section and locate `Chrome Type`
- Select `Title`
- Click `OK`

This will display a title within your WebPart and clicking on title you will navigated to view all list items.

Let me know if i guess the correct scenario.